# Bookmark icon not showing - Android 5.1.1 & Chrome

Tags: android, html, icons, favicon, bookmarks

`Hello`,

I have seen other posts about this, but the solutions did not work for me.
I have a OnePlus 2 running Android 5.1.1 and Chrome 45.0.2454.94, and a website, [daltonempire.nl](http://daltonempire.nl).

I'd like the icon to show on my homescreen of my phone when I add the bookmark of my site. Instead, it shows just the letter D on a grey, dull background [[2](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?site=www.daltonempire.nl&ignore_root_issues=on#.Vhlh7pkrJUN)].

I have got this piece of HTMl in my `<head>` to ensure compatibility, but to no avail, it seems.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/ico/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png?v=3">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/ico/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png?v=3">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/ico/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png?v=3">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/ico/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png?v=3">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/ico/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png?v=3">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/ico/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png?v=3">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/ico/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png?v=3">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/ico/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png?v=3">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/ico/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png?v=3">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/ico/favicon-32x32.png?v=3" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/ico/android-chrome-192x192.png?v=3" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/ico/favicon-96x96.png?v=3" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/ico/favicon-16x16.png?v=3" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="/ico/manifest.json?v=3">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/ico/favicon.ico?v=3">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="DaltonEmpire">
<meta name="application-name" content="DaltonEmpire">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#59a4c3">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ico/mstile-144x144.png?v=3">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/ico/browserconfig.xml?v=3">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#59a4c3">
```

The files are in that folder present, and the [favicon validator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?site=www.daltonempire.nl&ignore_root_issues=on#.Vhlh7pkrJUN) says this HTML is enough to ensure all bookmarks are presented as icons. Why is this not the case for me on Android 5.1.1, and how do I change this?

---

**EDIT:** The favicon is loaded [[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjxSg.jpg)], presumably it just searches for `daltonempire.nl/favicon.ico` and finds it there (I put it there as well), so it might not be relevant for my non-working code as it doesn't have to get that from there. It doesn't include the theme colour for example, as that would have been defined in my code. Also, I have tried removing the synchronization with my Google account, deleting the Cache & User Data from Chrome deleting the bookmark and then re-adding it, but to no avail.

I hope someone will be able to help me out,
With kind regards,

Isaiah van Hunen

---

Attachments: [[2](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?site=www.daltonempire.nl&ignore_root_issues=on#.Vhlh7pkrJUN)]

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When I add your site to my home screen with Android Chrome, I get the proper icon (the blue circle with the open book). Which browser do you use to test this? Because builtin browsers are know to produce poor results.

Comment: @philippe_b thanks for checking! I am using Chrome and would expect that to work... Which browser did you use?

Comment: Hum... strange. I'm using Chrome 45 on Android 5.0. I have a Galaxy S5. I have the proper icon and also the theme color, so Chrome really uses the manifest (and not the 192x192 PNG icon, which is for older versions of Android Chrome, prior 39 if I remember well).

Comment: @philippe_b hmm... I am using Android 5.1.1 on a OnePlus 2, running Chrome 45.0.2454.94... What might be relevant is that it synchronises with my desktop bookmarks, though I have already tried removing the bookmark, either adding it to the folder "Mobile bookmarks" and "Desktop bookmarks" and then adding it to my homescreen. Possibly I could refresh the image cache of Chrome? My phone is rooted..

Comment: Chrome is up-to-date I suppose? Ah... this is when we love computer science :) Maybe this is due to a caching issue, in particular if you added your site to the home screen before installing the icon for Android Chrome. You can try to explicitly refresh the home page in Chrome, or add another page to the home screen (not the homepage), in order to force Chrome to pay attention to your icon settings.

Comment: @philippe_b Chrome is up to date :)  I tried adding the downloads page of my website, it includes the same code snippets, but still that ugly D. I will try googling on how to refresh Chrome's cache, possibly with my root, tomorrow. Until then, already thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @philippe_b I tried disabling the synchronisation between Chrome and my Google account, then deleted the cache and user data, deleted the bookmark and added it again...  To no avail, it seems :/ If anyone has any better ideas, I'd be glad to hear them.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the exact same issue!

Answer (score 0):

@scotchman
I haven't done anything to fix this, but I think it was a bug and in some update of Chrome it got fixed. 
Happy me :]